# Checking if current date exists in database using c#

Tags: c#, mysql, mongodb, winforms

I have a table which I want to insert data in it only **once** in a day 
and to implement that I want to check if current date already exists in 
the database by writing these lines

```
  DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
  MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `attendances` WHERE 
                                    `lecture_id` = '" + lecture_id + "' " +
                                  " AND `date` = '"+date.ToShortDateString()+"' ",con);
            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();
            if (reader.HasRows)
                MessageBox.Show("you can't insert");

            else MessageBox.Show("you can insert");
```

The date is inserted to the database in this format `xxxx-xx-xx` although using the same method for inserting, and `date.ToShortDateString()` returns the date in this format 
`xxxx/x/x` .

---

I checked inserting the date manually in the correct format but that also didn't work, I also tried using the `DATE` function in sql but that didn't work either.

Comment: C# supports prepared statements i advice you using them.. Also is this a program for the public use? If so you should not hardcode the MySQL user/password in the application because of existing `.NET` decompilers which can be used then they have your MySQL username and password.

Comment: @RaymondNijland You are correct, I have used prepared statements in my program but this was just for testing if the condition was correct, thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just apply format `string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`
And do not call `ToShortDateString()` in your SQL query

You also should use `SqlParameter` as your code is vulnerable for SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 1):

You could also avoid using .NET's DateTime and use MySql's NOW() or UTC_DATE() instead within your query, which may be better; if the region of your code and db reside in different timezones.

i.e.

```
[...] " AND `date` = DATE(NOW()) ",con);
```